# Mongo search child documents after finding single document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following structure for my mongo data and am trying to get the distance from one zip code to another.  So I have zip1 98345 and zip2 of 98341, how can I get the miles between?  If there is a better way to structure this data, please let me know that (and the query to get the miles).  Thanks!

```
{ "zip" : 98345, 
"zips" : [ 
{   "to" : 98453,   "distances" : {     "miles" : 1,    "km" : 0 } },   
{   "to" : 98341,   "distances" : {     "miles" : 3.9,  "km" : 4.7 }, ...
]
},
{ "zip" : 98323, 
"zips" : [ 
{   "to" : 98395,   "distances" : {     "miles" : 1,    "km" : 0 } },   
{   "to" : 98373,   "distances" : {     "miles" : 3.9,  "km" : 4.7 }, ...
]
}, ....
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this with a simple find.  Here is one of them:

```
db.zips.find( { "zip":98345, "zips.to":98341},
              {"zip":1, "zips.$.distances":1,_id:0})
{ "zip" : 98345, "zips" : [ { "to" : 98341, "distances" : { "miles" : 3.9, "km" : 4.7 } } ] }
```

This says, match the document having zip 98345 and having zips array member to:98341 and return to me zip and just the matching array element from that document.

Comment: doesn't this return the km also. The question was for just miles. Do you know how to filter out the km part ?

Comment: this does appear to work directly in mongodb. My apologies but I am actually using meteor which uses mongo but in a slightly different way.  Any idea for how to do this in meteor?

Answer (score 0):

`$unwind` should help here.

Please test this out.

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate(
  { $unwind : "$zips"},
  { $match : {"zip" :98345, "zips.to" : 98341}},
  { $project : {"zips.distances.miles" :1, _id:0}}
);
```